# Differences between 理解する and 分かる

Tags: word-choice

Is there a difference between 理解する、and 分かる?
They all seem to mean "understand" but I cannot figure their difference:

Here is some context:

> 彼らは誰よりも深くお互いを**理解**し‌た
>
> ```
> They understood each other better than anyone else.
> ```

Comment: Your question seems a bit too vague, if you look up the three words in a dictionary you'll see that they are clearly different, especially 把握.

Comment: OK Ben I reformulated the question so its domain is more narrow

Comment: OK I'll try to answer, but there is a duplicate here: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/33826/%e3%82%8a%e3%81%8b%e3%81%84-%e3%81%97%e3%81%be%e3%81%99-or-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99/33856#33856

Answer (score 5, accepted):

理解する is very close to わかる in one of its meanings, to understand something.

人の気持ちを理解する - OK

人の気持ちがわかる　- OK

理解する is transitive and takes を whereas わかる takes が. 理解する is a kango (漢語) word consisting of a kanji pair plus suru, so it tends to be used in more formal contexts.

The use of わかる and わからない to mean "know/don't know" is not interchangeable with 理解する:

brother: 僕のカギどこ？

sister: わからない - OK

brother: 僕のカギどこ？

sister: 理解しない・理解できない - wrong or at least strange-sounding

Comment: Could you add an example where わかる doesn't work but 理解する does? Would help me a lot, thanks